# Expiration notification

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, web-applications, windows-server-2008

What is the most straightforward way to send a notification e-mail to customers after 12 months from purchase date?

Our web server runs a ASP.NET MVC 3 website connected to SQL Server. Currently we run manually a web page every Monday that notifies expired users.

Here are the options I have in mind so far:

1. Running the web page daily using the Task Scheduler
2. Build a console application that continuously check the timer and eventually sends notifications
3. Build a windows service like 2) that in case of failure can be restarted automatically

Am I missing something easier?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had same problem in my previous company. AT the end we went for Task Scheduler. The main reason is that **Task Scheduler is the standard mechanism for dealing with repetitive tasks in Windows** so is more maintainable in the future than other options.

Our console app run by Task Scheduler everyday and it was designed to be "smart". By smart I mean.

- The console app was a dummy application that invoked a WCF service. All the logic was inside of the WCF service. The reason for this was keeping all the code in the same place.
- If failed to run raised an alarm writing in our System Log (It was checked daily, it was a DB table). In case of catastrophic fail (no access to DB) we wrote to a file in console app directory.
- If it was already in process, a second instance was not allowed to run (Some sort of Singleton)
- It keep track in DB which emails were sent so, in case of executing it twice the same day, only the first time send the email.
- It had a **/whatif** parameter
- If an email failed, it was logged and the process continued.
- If it had to send several emails and failed at some moment, the next execution would pick up from the point it stopped.

Internally the code was something like

```
Linq to get all the users that deserved an email
For each user
  Send the email, mark it as sent in DB and close transaction
  If email fails Write to log.
Next
Write log with stats
```

This way it was slower but safer. If it had to send an email to 4000 users and failed in user 1337 then we had a log of what happened and the next time it was executed it will resume from 1338.

In our **system log** in one folder we had usually an entry everyday saying something like:

> Email process started at 02:00 by Scheduler. 4000 emails sent, 0 failed.

If something failed:

> Email process started at 02:00 by Scheduler. 3999 emails sent, 1 failed. 
>   Email to user xxxxx failed. Reason: Email address "joeBlogs@@gmail.com" is incorrect.

Comment: What's the benefit of using a WCF service instead of a classic Console app?

Comment: Not a big one. Mainly to have **all logic is in the same place**. Also is more **easy to reuse** its functionality. For example you can have a web page that manually triggers the update calling same process. Or even have another web page that runs in /whatif mode and tells which users would receive an email if process is launch.